# Preseed Multiple Disks

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partition, preseed

I have machines in my environment with either 1 or 2 disks/arrays.

I would like preseed to use all disk space regardless of how many the box has.

The problem is: My current partitioning scheme hangs up as soon as it sees multiple disks.

Here's what my preseed looks like for partitioning:

```
# Partitioning
d-i partman-auto/method string lvm
# If one of the disks that are going to be automatically partitioned
# contains an old LVM configuration, the user will normally receive a
# warning. This can be preseeded away...
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
# The same applies to pre-existing software RAID array:
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
# And the same goes for the confirmation to write the lvm partitions.
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
# You can choose one of the three predefined partitioning recipes:
# - atomic: all files in one partition
# - home:   separate /home partition
# - multi:  separate /home, /var, and /tmp partitions
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic

# This makes partman automatically partition without confirmation, provided
# that you told it what to do using one of the methods above.
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true

# Choose automatic partitioning recipes where automatic puts
# All configuration on the same partition
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select automic
# Complete partitioning without further confirmation
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
```

My Question: How do I make preseed use all available disks regardless of how many are detected?

Alternatively: How do I make preseed install on the first partition and then create a blank partition on the secondary disks?

Answer (score 1):

Without testing, it appears this line -

```
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select automic
```

should really be -

```
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic
```

(notice 'atomic', instead of 'automic')
Give that a try.